# oversized data during truffle migrate

Tags: genesis

In Quorum, while deploying a 54KB smart contract via truffle migrate, I am getting the error "oversized data"

Tried adding maxCodeSize to genesis.json but did not work

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue by increasing the transaction size to 64KB in tx_pool.go

DOS is less applicable for private Ethereum networks such as Quorum.

// Heuristic limit, reject transactions over 32KB to prevent DOS attacks

// UPDATED to 64KB to support the deployment of bigger contract due to the pressing need for sophisticated/complex contract in financial/capital markets - Nathan Aw

```
if tx.Size() > 64*1024 {
    return ErrOversizedData
}
```

References:

https://github.com/nathanawmk/quorum/blob/master/core/tx_pool.go